# Can I call Cakephp validation via static methods?

Tags: cakephp

I want to use the built in validations in cakephp 2.  Just like password hashing:

```
AuthComponent::password()
```

I have tried:

```
Validation::email($email)
```

But that gives a fatal error (class not found etc.).  Is there a quick way/hack of using it in a static way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the method is declared static (public static function) - which it is in your case - you can do so.
But you still need to tell Cake where to look for.

So if you havent used/included the class yet, you need

```
App::uses('Validation', 'Utility');
```

prior to calling any of its methods.